# WebStorm 12 EAP - JavaScript debug configuration doesn't work with built-in webserver

Tags: webserver, webstorm, built-in, javascript-debugger

I am trying to start debugging session using built-in WebStorm server after I created a new JavaScript debug configuration. I am using this project:

https://github.com/pauldessert/SeedTip.git

[image]

I am experiencing this weird problem that all of my locally referenced `.css` and `.js` files:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/map.js"></script>
<script src="js/search.js"></script>
```

...could not be found/loaded by the browser. I show this in bellow image when I pressed F12 to see Chrome Dev tools (this action seems to disconnect WebStorm IDE support extension) and you can see failed requests.

You can see in the console tool window in WebStorm that there were get request for .css and .js local files. When I press any of these links it opens ok in my Chrome browser.

E.g. this file does exist:

**`http://localhost:63342/SeedTip/css/style.css`**

When I use an external node server e.g. grunt-serve and create JS debug configuration with URL: `http://localhost:9000/index.html` pointing to:
`F:\Projects\Angular\v2\SeedTip` and run this debug it works.

Note: I have the same problem with enabling Angular 2 apps to load with systemjs.
I tried setting   but it doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21447 and/or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21319 -- they are marked as fixed. See if it will be OK in next EAP/release.

Comment: Yes. I checked it is fixed with the latest build. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was a known bug, that was fixed in the latest build.