# WebStorm - refreshing JavaScript debug results in 404

Tags: webstorm, web-deployment, page-refresh, built-in-web-server

I am currently using WebStorm as my IDE to develop an angular 2 project. I switched over from Netbeans due to the lack of ES6 compiling.
So far I don't regret my decision.

HOWEVER there is a slight annoyance that make me crave for netbeans again. The built-in webserver.  In NetBeans it was possible to refresh your url (localhost:xxx:PROJECT/index.html) and it would show the changes. In WebStorm (at least for me) the webserver stops? Resulting in a 404.

[image: Error 404 after Refresh]

I am having to re-run for every change, making me lose a lot of precious time. Is there a work around or are my run settings flawed?

A screenshot of the run setting that I am using:

[image: WebStorm run setting]

Comment: Maybe the refresh clear the cache?

Comment: That would be on odd way to base a webserver upon.

Comment: Try latest [2016.1.2 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP). Could be the same reasons as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/36997921/783119 . If not fixed there -- then it should be in 2016.2 (e.g. if it's a different ticket -- e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20807 )

Comment: did you tried with nodemon configuration https://samkirkiles.svbtle.com/webstorm-node-js-debugging-with-nodemon